# Why check these two conditions before removing element from a list?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i'm learning about arraylist now, and i no have idea, why somebody removing last element like this:

```
l = list.size();
```

.

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
    list.remove(l);}
```

this is not the same as:

```
                if (list != null ) {
                    list.remove(l);}
```

or

```
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    list.remove(l);}
```

? Somebody can explain it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `null` reference is not the same as a list with no contents.

`list.isEmpty()` will throw an NPE if `list` is `null`.

`list.remove(l)` will throw an exception if the list is empty.

So you need both.

Comment: when list is null and when is empty ?

Comment: @forschool ... It's empty when there's nothing in it. It's `null` when it hasn't been initialized, or it's been set to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `list != null` you are checking if the variable `list` is null or not. Take for example the following piece of code:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

The variable `al` won't be `null` as we have assigned it to a `new ArrayList()`, but it will be empty as it doesn't contain any elements.

```
ArrayList al;
```

In the above example, `al` will be `null` as it hasn't been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

`list.isEmpty()` checks whether the current list is empty. So `!list.isEmpty()` will return `true` **IF** the list is **NOT** empty. This check is done to make sure that there is at least 1 element in the list to be removed, as you cannot "remove" an element from an empty list. If you try removing something from an empty list, it will throw `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

> this is not the same as...

Definitely! `if (list != null )` will return true if the ArrayList object is initialized.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(...);
```

The above statement initializes the arraylist object `list`. You have to initialize the object before you do anything or you'll get a `NullPointer` exception. The two condition checks make sure you don't encounter any of these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You check if `list != null` because if it is null, you will get a `NullPointerException`. List is null when you declare it without initializing like `List<String> list;` instead of `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`;

You check if `!list.isEmpty()` because if it is empty, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. List is empty if you do not add any elements to it, like `list.add("Some string");`.

`if (list != null && !list.isEmpty())` requires both of these conditions to be true and therefore prevents those exceptions from occuring.

Also you can not remove last element by calling `list.remove(list.size());` because lists do indexing from 0 and size starts counting from 1. So if you `list.size()` returns 10, the last element of your list is indexed 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
int l = list.size()
//(...)
list.remove(l);
```

Will actually give you an out of bounds exception... The last index is .size()-1.
Safely removing the last element of a list thus should be:

```
if (list!=null && list.size()>0) list.remove(list.size()-1);
```

As the others already said you need to make sure the list actually exists (therefore list!=null) and that it actually contains elements (list.size()>0 or !list.isEmpty()).
Lastly you tell the list to remove the element at its highest index (size - 1) which is also the last element.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave Newton explains concrete reasons of the check : protecting from Runtime Exception if the list is not in expected state.

But this code to remove the last element has still two problems.

```
l = list.size();        
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
    list.remove(l);
}
```

1) It will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException as `list.remove(list.size())` is after the last index of the List.

2) The way of coding seems to be a bad smell :

Generally when an operation modifying the state of  a list (add, delete, update), the List should be already not null.
Otherwise it forces all methods using the List to check if it is not null before  using it.

Besides,  `l = list.size();` should be invoked only if the list is not empty.
Why declaring it before ?

So this code is generally enough :

```
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    list.remove(list.size()-1);
}
```

if `list` is initialized before (in a constructor for example).